# How to set interactivity on multiple columns in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I'm trying to create a sublayer with interactivity on it for a tooltip. The tooltip is going to need data from a column named plant_name. So I am setting the interactivity property as I create the sublayer, like this:

```
        sublayer = layer.createSubLayer(
          sql: sql,
          cartocss: css
          interactivity: ["cartodb_id", "plant_name"]
        )
```

The problem is I get an error saying ["layer1: Postgis Plugin: ERROR: column "plant_name" does not exist."](http://bit.ly/NsFndK) even though the column is in the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the column exist in ```sql```?

Comment: Yeah, totally, it's there.

Comment: Ah, scratch that. My mistake. The column wasn't in the SQL.

Comment: Please, could you add your comment as the answer of this question so that the rest of the community can see that it was solved? :)

Comment: sublayer = layer.createSubLayer( sql: sql, cartocss: css interactivity: "cartodb_id, plant_name" )