# Setting interactivity on sublayer created in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I am trying to set the interactivity on a sublayer that I created on CartoDB web interface so that my events and tooltips receive the correct fields as arguments of the callback functions. Here is how I have tried to do this:

```
    layers[1].setInteraction(true)
    poverty_layer = layers[1].getSubLayer(0)
    poverty_layer.set("interactivity", ["cartodb_id, namelsad10, hh_median"])

    poverty_layer.on "featureOver", (e,ll,pos,data)->
      console.log data
```

I assumed that by doing this I would see three data fields –– cartodb_id, namelsad10, and  hh_median –– but I only see cartodb_id. I already managed to [set interactivity successfully on sublayers that are created on the clientside](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88515/how-to-set-interactivity-on-multiple-columns-in-cartodb). This is the one use case where it hasn't been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax apparently is as follows:

```
poverty_layer.setInteractivity("field1, field2, field3")
```

Or alternatively:

```
poverty_layer.set({interactivity: "field1, field2, field3"})
```